# Pre-populate Gravity Form with multiple values from ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, gravity-forms-plugin

Here is a simple example of what I am trying to achieve:

I have a gravity form with different sections that will be shown conditionally by pre-populating dynamically. The thing is that I can't seem to populate them based on my ACF data (which are checkboxes as well).

If I put the values into the code it works like this:

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_2', 'my_populate_checkbox' );
function my_populate_checkbox( $form ) {

  foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {

    if( 11 === $field->id ) {

      foreach( $field->choices as &$choice ) {

        if( 'mychoice' === $choice['value'] || 'anotherchoice' === $choice['value'] ) {
          $choice['isSelected'] = true;
        }
      } 
    } 
  } 

  return $form;
}
```

To get it to be populated dynamically I was trying something like this which didn't work (not that good with php):

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_2', 'my_populate_checkbox' );
function my_populate_checkbox( $form ) {

  foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {

    if( 11 === $field->id ) {

      foreach( $field->choices as &$choice ) {

        $addons = get_field('addons');

        if( $addons === $choice['value'] ) {
          $choice['isSelected'] = true;
        }
      } 
    } 
  } 

  return $form;
}
```

It's not working and I know I am missing something here but can't figure out what it is:/ Any help or pointers would be highly appreciated! I tried keeping it precise but if any more information is required please let me know and I will update the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with some help:) In case anybody needs this functionality, here is how it works:

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_2', 'my_populate_checkbox' );
function my_populate_checkbox( $form ) {
  global $post;
  $adfields = get_field( 'addons', get_the_ID() );

  foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {

    if( 11 === $field->id ) {

      foreach( $field->choices as &$choice ) {

        if( in_array( $choice['value'] ,$adfields )) {
          $choice['isSelected'] = true;
        }
      } 
    } 
  } 

  return $form;
}
```